# TypeError: data.itemNo is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am getting this error when trying to access my observable from the data context value. `TypeError: data.itemNo is not a function`

Here is my Knockout:

```
var TallyModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        self.itemNo = ko.observable();
        self.qty = ko.observable();
        self.price = ko.observable();
        self.bro = ko.observable();
        self.desc = ko.observable();
        self.extend = ko.observable();
        self.total = ko.observable();
        self.seq = ko.observable();
    }

    var TallyViewModel = function (items) {
        var self = this;

        if(items != null) {
            self.items = ko.observableArray(items.map(function(item) { return new TallyModel(item) }));
        }
        else {
            self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
        }

        self.addLine = function() {
            var tModel = new TallyModel();
            self.items.push( tModel );
        };

        self.insertLine = function(index) {
            self.items.splice(index, 0, new TallyModel() );
        };

        self.removeItem = function(index) {
            console.log(self.items().length);
            if(self.items().length > 1) {
                self.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
        };

        self.checkItemNo = function(data, index) {
            console.log(data);
            **var itemNo = $.trim(data.itemNo());**
            console.log(itemNo);
            $.each(validItems, function (i, elem) {
                if (elem.itemNo == itemNo) {
                    data.price(elem.retail);
                    data.bro(elem.brocCode);
                    data.desc(elem.itemDesc);
                    data.extend(elem.extPrice);
                    data.seq(index);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("could not find " + itemNo + " - " + elem.itemNo);
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

As requested here is the HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: itemNo, insertPress: $index, deletePress: $index, event: { blur: $parent.checkItemNo.bind($data, $index) }, attr: { name: 'itemNo[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemNo[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: qty, insertPress: $index, tabEnterPress: '#tallyEntry', deletePress: $index, attr: { name: 'itemQty[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemQty[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: price, attr: { name: 'itemPrice[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemPrice[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: bro, attr: { name: 'itemBro[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemBro[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: desc, attr: { name: 'itemDesc[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemDesc[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: extend, attr: { name: 'itemExtend[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemExtend[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: total, attr: { name: 'itemTotal[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemTotal[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: seq, attr: { name: 'itemSeq[' + $index() + ']', id: 'itemSeq[' + $index() + ']' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I have bolded/starred the culprit line in the code.  It was working and I must have changed something, not sure why it is no longer working.  Let me know if I need to post the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: what you see when you `console.log(data)` ? `itemNo` as `function` or `Number`

Comment: Please provide full example. I can't see here place where `checkItemNo` calls from. Something wrong with argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the function

```
blur: $parent.checkItemNo.bind($data, $index)
```

But `bind`'s first argument is `thisArg`. It would probably just be easier to use this syntax

```
blur: function(){ $parent.checkItemNo($data, $index); }
```

Comment: Don't fully understand it, but this fixed it!  Thanks!  What is `thisArg`?